# No application servers available in settings

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ IDA 12.1.6 Ultimate and having installed Tomcat 7, I have no available application servers under IDE Settings via
Application Servers -> +. There is an empty list with text "Nothing here". How do I make IntelliJ aware of the location of the Tomcat install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to install the integrations under `IDE SETTINGS` -> `Plugins`.

For example when using Apache Tomcat, the plugin is named "Tomcat and TomEE integrations"

Comment: Any idea what do I do if I don't even have "Application servers" section in my IntelliJ settings?

Comment: @DanielGruszczyk Is it possible that you are using the Community-Edition? `Application Servers` are not supported in this edition. See [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)